# SQL Query running slow on the DB server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Execution plan is [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2lqB.jpg)

```
SELECT a.*, k.UserPrivileges, k.Type
FROM NotifyInterests2 a, KUAF k
WHERE a.UserID = k.ID
AND EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM KUAF WHERE a.UserID = ID AND NOT Type IN (1, 2, 4))
AND (a.NodeID IN ( SELECT 0 UNION ALL ( SELECT DISTINCT( -1 * ID )
FROM KUAF WHERE Type = 5 ) UNION ALL ( SELECT DISTINCT AncestorID
FROM DTreeAncestors 
WHERE Exists ( SELECT EventInt2 FROM LLEventQueue     
WHERE EventHandlerID = 9001 AND EventSeqNo <=45075882 AND EventInt2 = DataID    
UNION ALL SELECT EventInt2 * -1 FROM LLEventQueue 
WHERE EventHandlerID = 9001    
AND EventSeqNo <=45075882 AND EventInt2 = DataID ))))
```

Comment: User is saying we need to reduce fragmentation on the indexes first.

Comment: i have collected data for indexes and most of the indexes are Heap tables where fragmentation is more than 80% and there are few non clustered and clustered indexes also with 70% fragmentation

Comment: Index rebuild job is scheduled to run twice a week, I strongly believe that this query needs optimization rather than defragmentation on indexes

Comment: 40 rows as a output of query ,but whenever this query gets called it will go into hang state.

Answer (score 0):

that's quite the query =) Tip: try to 'group' the parts of your code for readability; it will make your life a 100 times easier; now while you're writing this and even more in the future when you're maintaining this =)

Some questions remain:

- What do you call 'slow'?
- How many records are present in each table?
- How many records are returned by the query?
- What are the indexes on the tables? (sp_helpindex)

Also, it probably would have been helpful to see the entire query plan, but one thing that stands out immediately is that KEAF doesn't seem to have clustered index. I presume it's thus also missing a Primary Key? As you have a field ID there I'd expect that this uniquely identifies each record? If so, add a PK to the table and check what effect this has on the entire query.

I've tried to re-arrange things a bit for readability and I ended up with below. I've gambled on some of the aliases as they are missing in the original query.

```
SELECT a.*, k.UserPrivileges, k.Type
  FROM NotifyInterests2 a
  JOIN KUAF k
    ON k.ID = a.UserID
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT kx.ID 
                  FROM KUAF kx
                 WHERE kx.ID = a.UserID
                   AND NOT kx.Type IN (1, 2, 4) )

   AND  a.NodeID IN ( SELECT 0 

                       UNION ALL 

                      SELECT DISTINCT( -1 * k5.ID )
                        FROM KUAF k5
                       WHERE k5.Type = 5 

                       UNION ALL 

                      SELECT DISTINCT da.AncestorID
                        FROM DTreeAncestors da
                       WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT l1.EventInt2 
                                        FROM LLEventQueue l1
                                       WHERE l1.EventHandlerID = 9001 
                                         AND l1.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                         AND l1.EventInt2 = da.DataID

                                       UNION ALL 
                                  
                                      SELECT l2.EventInt2 * -1 
                                        FROM LLEventQueue l2
                                       WHERE l2.EventHandlerID = 9001
                                         AND l2.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                         AND l2.EventInt2 = da.DataID )
            )
```

Some parts can be simplified I think.
This doesn't really make sense:

```
                      SELECT DISTINCT da.AncestorID
                        FROM DTreeAncestors da
                       WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT l1.EventInt2 
                                        FROM LLEventQueue l1
                                       WHERE l1.EventHandlerID = 9001 
                                         AND l1.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                         AND l1.EventInt2 = da.DataID

                                       UNION ALL 
                                  
                                      SELECT l2.EventInt2 * -1 
                                        FROM LLEventQueue l2
                                       WHERE l2.EventHandlerID = 9001
                                         AND l2.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                         AND l2.EventInt2 = da.DataID )
```

You're simply doing the same query twice in the `WHERE EXISTS()` part.
Also, as this part belongs to a `WHERE IN (...)` construction there's no real need for the `DISTINCT`. In fact, it's probably easier to convert it to a `WHERE EXISTS()` construction. Something like this:

```
   AND (  a.NodeID = 0
       OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM KUAF k5
                   WHERE k5.Type = 5 
                     AND ( -1 * k5.ID ) = a.node_id)

       OR EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM DTreeAncestors da
                    WHERE da.AncestorID = a.NodeID
                      AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                     FROM LLEventQueue l1
                                    WHERE l1.EventHandlerID = 9001 
                                      AND l1.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                      AND l1.EventInt2 = da.DataID )
            )
```

Normally I'm no fan of `OR` but I think that in this case it might work.

So I end up with:

```
SELECT a.*, k.UserPrivileges, k.Type
  FROM NotifyInterests2 a
  JOIN KUAF k
    ON k.ID = a.UserID
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT kx.ID 
                  FROM KUAF kx
                 WHERE a.UserID = kx.ID 
                   AND NOT kx.Type IN (1, 2, 4) )

   AND (  a.NodeID = 0
       OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM KUAF k5
                   WHERE k5.Type = 5 
                     AND ( -1 * k5.ID ) = a.node_id)

       OR EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM DTreeAncestors da
                    WHERE da.AncestorID = a.NodeID
                      AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                     FROM LLEventQueue l
                                    WHERE l.EventHandlerID = 9001 
                                      AND l.EventSeqNo <= 45075882 
                                      AND l.EventInt2 = da.DataID )
                 )
     )
```

Give this a try and check the query plan. If it still is too slow we'll need to look at the indexes that are on the bespoken tables to see where we can optimize those.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if and which indexes exist in the table.
I would try creating the following indexes and see if there is any performance gain:

```
CREATE INDEX kuaf_idx_id_type ON KUAF (ID,Type);
CREATE INDEX kuaf_idx_type ON KUAF (Type);
CREATE INDEX lleventqueue_idx_eventha_eventin_dataid_eventse ON LLEventQueue (EventHandlerID,EventInt2,DataID,EventSeqNo);
```